# How can I load many files into mysql automatically add date information?

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I have many files, for example: 20170319, 20170320 ...
For each file I have 2 columns, one for username and the other was data.
I've created a table

```
create table A(user varchar(35), date date, data varchar(35), primary key(user, date));
```

Then, I want to load those files into database, and use filename as specific date in date field.

Can I still use sth like:

```
Load data infile '20170320' into table A
```

Comment: have a look at `SET` in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html). You should be able to add a custom column with the date this way.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you cannot do this in MySQL alone, you need to use an external program or script that builds the `load data infile` statements with the appropriate [SET clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) derived from the name of the file:

> The SET clause can be used to supply values not derived from the input
>   file. The following statement sets column3 to the current date and
>   time:
>
> ```
> LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
>   INTO TABLE t1
>   (column1, column2)
>   SET column3 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
> ```

The reason for this is that:

1. `load data infile` cannot use the file name as an input variable
2. neither MySQL prepared statements using the [prepare statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), nor [stored procedures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html) are allowed to use the `load data infile` statement.